# How to make a div appear on a screen all the time, even when there is no content present in it

Tags: html, css

I want to make a standard frame with two `divs` side by side.

```css
.test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.test22 {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="test22">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zvy0j3r1/

Now as you can see with a fixed height on 2nd `div` I'm able to see the container with black bgcolor on the screen. But I cannot have a fixed height as the content is variable and hence I changed: `height:100%`  instead of fixed height.

When I do that, I don't see anything on the screen, except the border I added

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zvy0j3r1/1/

If I add some content in it, it'll start showing up:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zvy0j3r1/2/

but I want to be able to see the black container always whether I have content or not with `height: 100%`?

Is this possible?

Comment: this question was asked so many times. Find out yourself https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+div+height

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, not a jsfiddle. [mcve] A fiddle can compliment your example but not be used in its stead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height: 100%` means that it will takes 100% of its parent's height.
In this case, the parent block is Body, which has no height defined, so it will be 100% of nothing.

First thing you have to do, is to define an height for both **body** and **html** tags.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Then, use `min-height` instead of `height` so the size will always fit its content.

```
.test22 {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

---

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.test {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
   
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting to work with the content inside the ```div```, what I'm trying to ask is is it possible to show the container always w/o having to enter any text, i.e if I remove the text entered inside ```test``` div, the ```div``` with just bgcolor wont show up, is there a way to show that

Comment: See my update, w/o text. It's all about `min-height`'s value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-height`:

```css
.container {
  min-height: 60px;
  background-color: #e3dcff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  I have content
</div>


<div class="container">
<!-- no content -->
</div>


<div class="container">
  I have very long content<br/>
  I have very long content<br/>
  I have very long content<br/>
  I have very long content<br/>
  I have very long content<br/>
  I have very long content<br/>
  I have very long content<br/>
  I have very long content<br/>
  I have very long content<br/>
  I have very long content<br/>
  I have very long content<br/>
  And I adapt my height
</div>
```

Comment: `min-height` doesn't work if you don't have an explicit height you want to set it to. In this case it should be however high the viewport is, e.g. dynamic.